# A question regarding a paper of M. Magidor

Tags: reference-request, logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

I am interested in the following paper of M. Magidor:

"On the role of supercompact and extendible cardinals in logic", Israel Journal of Mathematics, 05/1971;  10(2): 147-157.

The abstract (which I got from www.researchgate.net) reads as follows:

"It is proved that the existence of [a] supercompact cardinal is equivalent to a certain Skolem-Lowenheim Theorem for second order logic, whereas the existence of [an] extendible cardinal is equivalent to a certain compactness theorem for that logic.  It is also proved that a certain axiom scheme related to model theory implies the existence of many extendible cardinals."

I have several questions related to this paper:

i)  What is the axiomatization of second-order logic he uses in this paper?

ii)  Do the "Skolem-Lowenheim Theorem for second-order logic" and the "compactness theorem for that logic" hold for the 'full semantics' for second-order logic or just the Henkin models?

iii)  As it has been claimed by some (Quine, for instance) that second-order logic is 'set theory in sheep's clothing', is the "axiom schema related to model theory" he refers to in that paper derivable as a theorem in the second-order logic he refers to in the paper?

Any help you could give me regarding answering these questions will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems silly to ask us questions that can be easily answered by looking at the paper, just because you're impatient and want to know now rather than after the holiday.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Are you by chance familiar with this paper?  If so, are you confirming that the answers to the questions I asked are found within the paper itself?

Comment: I have looked at it before. I don't remember anything concrete, or I'd have posted an answer.

Comment: @Andres Caicedo, et al:  This question is about understanding Magidor's results that are found in his paper.  This definitely fits the definition of "mathematics within the scope defined in the help center". Please explain your reasoning regarding for deeming my question as "off-topic".

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin: Just overlook any condescending words :) I just came across this question and stopped by. Sometimes, yes, things like your case happen here.

Comment: @Chou, Thomas: The question is "I'm too impatient to wait until after the holiday". It is deservedly closed, and shouldn't have been asked in the first place. After looking at the paper, it's fine if you have questions, whatever they might be. It is not fine to say "Hey, I will only look at the paper in a few days, but in the meantime... please someone let me know what's in the paper".

Comment: @AsafKaragila: According to the present version of this question, indeed I am not sure where the question "I'm too ..." is implied. I am not saying that no question is deserved to be closed.

Comment: @Chou: Omitting the information makes this even worse. Since we already know that in a week or so the OP can find the answers on their own accord.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  I have had a copy of Magidor's paper since January and nowhere does his paper answer the questions I asked.  Since the paper was part of his PhD thesis, perhaps the answers lie therein.  Is there a downloadable copy of Magidor's thesis available? Please let me know.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: (cont.) It should be noted that the "axiom schema related to model theory" is Vopenka's principle (so perhaps iii) is not a good question), and a semblance of an answer to i) is found in Magidor's and Vaananen's paper "On Lowenheim-Skolem-Tarski numbers for extensions of first-order logic", but ii) still puzzles me. Anyone who can provide an answer to ii) should let me know.